# How can I execute Windows commands from Perl without leaving command windows open?

Tags: windows, perl, cmd

I have a Perl script on Win10 that uses the system() command to run a couple of different command line processes, including:

1. Start Windows Media Player with a specified .mp3 file.

   my $cmd = "start call wmplayer.exe myRadoShow.mp3";

   system($cmd);
2. Start another Perl program that does something else at the same time (specifically reads and broadcasts a set of timecodes and titles).

   my $cmd2 = "secondScript.pl *some_params*";

   system($cmd2);

All of this works correctly; the minor problem is that #1 above starts up a new command line window each time it executes the system($cmd) command. I have to later go back and close those windows.

If I don't use "start call" the Perl script doesn't continue to #2.

Is there a preferred way to execute #1 that doesn't leave these windows open?

I realize this question may be more about Windows commands than Perl.

Comment: `system(1, ... )`, a Windows-only usage of `system` documented in perlport, can launch a program without waiting. Obviously, you could use the actual Window system call `CreateProcess` through a number of modules. IPC::Run allows you to run programs in parallel, but I think they need to be started at the same time??

Comment: One thing's for sure, you certainly do not need the command `call`, which is only used for running one batch file from a cmd.exe process and continuing from the next line when that script has completed, or running one labelled section of a batch file from elsewhere in that same batch file, and continuing from the next command once completed. `wmplayer.exe` is not a batch file, so the `call` command serves absolutely no purpose. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `call /?` and ptess the `[ENTER]` key to see more information, or to verify the above.

Comment: @ikegami thanks for the tips - I haven't been able to find documentation on the Windows system call you mention, but IPC::Run looks promising.

Comment: @Compo I've discovered that removing the 'call' command from my system call triggers some other media player (the system default I think), so that's why I have it in there.

Comment: `system` doc in perlport: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlport#system

Comment: That's irrespective of my advice. Technically the command entered directly in `cmd.exe` is either, ```Start "" "P:\athTo\wmplayer.exe" "P:\athTo\myRadoShow.mp3"``` or ```Start "" /D "W:\orkingDir" "P:\athTo\wmplayer.exe” ”myRadoShow.mp3"```. So whichever one of those two you choose should be what `cmd.exe` receives, including the doublequotes. Try it from a Command Prompt window to confirm. Then all you need to do is make sure that you escape any of those nested doublequotes, if necessary, for it to work from `system()`.

Comment: and yes the double quotes after Start seems to do the trick, though I'm not sure I understand why :-)

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to see its usage information. What is not clear when reading it is that the first doublequoted string is generally read as the `"title"`. In my examples above, I have used an empty title, `""`, you are free, of course, to add your chosen string there instead if you prefer.

Comment: Re "*I haven't been able to find documentation on the Windows system call you mention,*", [`CreateProcessW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw)

Comment: @Compo, Better to avoid the shell and use `system(1, ...)` instead of `start`.

Comment: Re "*the double quotes after Start seems to do the trick*", Cause `start` expects the first argument to be the title of the window if it starts with `"`.

Comment: I already mentioned [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73920670/whats-the-proper-workflow-for-running-perl-on-win10-with-multiple-command-line?noredirect=1#comment130523798_73920670), @ikegami!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, If youre using active perl versions, there is a wperl.exe you can call your script with instead of the default perl.exe. Not to sure if this will hide sub processes created by your script but you can give it a go.

If that doesnt work, then maybe you can use Win32::GUI:

```
  use Win32::GUI;
  my $hw = Win32::GUI::GetPerlWindow();
  Win32::GUI::Hide($hw);
```

there are other modules that provide this functionality as well. Good luck!